# Intellij idea: how to extend the Java editor

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have managed to develop and run an intellij plugin. Would it be possible to create a plugin extending the java editor for instance by providing a custom code completion feature ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Please refer to the JavaDoc of the [CompletionContributor class](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/codeInsight/completion/CompletionContributor.java) for details of implementing custom code completion.